# lsusb lists Galaxy Samsung Tab s2 & adb devices lists nothing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, adb, linux

really, I do all my efforts  to run an android project through eclipse on a tablet `"Samsung galaxy Tab s2/ GT-P3100"` under linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

i add the vendor id of samsung  in  `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

```
   0x04e8
```

i add rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` as following :

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:ff420?:*", MODE="0666"
```

then , i restart udev  & i run the following command

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

i updates  `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
```

the thing that perplexed me is the listing of the tab when running the following cmd :

```
abdennour@estifeda1:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 125f:a11a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II]
```

And the device also is well mounted: 
[image]

I finally recourse a very [long solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/88481/159179) but, as usual, in vain :

Comment: Either you don't have ADB access enabled on the phone, or adb isn't aware that the Samsung is a possible adb device (because the the USB id is missing, see [this answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/341696/80242)) or adb hasn't the necessary access rights to the USB device (the askubuntu question has also an answer to this).

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution , it is a device matter and not Host matter: Hence, i am right when i wrote this question in https://android.stackexchange.com/ and not in askubuntu exchange.

Go to `Settings > Developer options> Developer options` .

Then, check : `USB Debugging` 
[image]